# On a Submarine VS In a Submarine

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Which preposition do we use when we're talking about submarines?? Like, are we in them or are we on them? Also, do we 'board' a submarine like we board a plane. And, can we say that I am on board a submarine?? Excuse my punctuation.

Answer (score 3):

Both are common (the iWeb corpus has 548 instances of *in a submarine* against 508 of *on a submarine*).

Looking at the examples there, I see a slight tendency to use them differently. When the focus is the journey or the destination, *in a submarine* (eg "See the Great Barrier Reef in a submarine"); where the focus is on the vehicle, *on a submarine* (eg "Like a sailor on a submarine").

But this is only slight, and both expressions are in use whatever the focus.

Certainly we can *board a submarine* (the expression was used with ships before there were aeroplanes!) and be *on board a submarine*.